# Cambiar submenú dinámicamente desde otro component

Tags: reactjs

Estoy haciendo una app usando **reactjs** y necesito que cuando cargue un determinado componente en el header me cargue un determinado menú para cada página en especifico es decir, que cuando entre en la url `/admin/users` en el header se me dibuje un menú con las opciones de *Usuarios | Roles | Permisos* y cuando entre en `/admin/agency` dibuje un menú con las opciones de *Agencia | Viajes | Reservaciones*

Comment: la idea es que se le pase como parametro al route o otra variante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Podes hacerlo de varias formas, trato de explicarte una utilizando react-router v4.**

Suponiendo que estamos creando una app  con ***create-react-app:***

En nuestro index.js (**punto de entrada de nuestra app)** importamos los modulos necesarios para poder utilizar nuestro router.

```
import App from './components/App/index'; // importamos nuestro component principal donde vamos a renderizar nuestras rutas.
import React from 'react'; // importamos react
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom' // importamos react-dom
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'// importamos mediante *object desctructuring (es6)* BrowserRouter que nos sirve cuando tenemos un servidor que se encargará de solicitudes dinámicas    

ReactDOM.render((

    <BrowserRouter> 
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>

), document.getElementById('root'))
```

Ahora que ya tenemos nuestro index.js con las configuraciones mínimas y basicas vamos a crear nuestro component App.js el cual va a contener nuestro ruteo.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; // importamos component mediande object destructuring 
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom' // importamos dos componentens escenciales para manejar nuestas rutas

import Home from '../Home/index' // componente que vamos a renderizar cuando la ruta de nuestra url coincida con el path de nuestro component Route
import NotFound  from '../NotFound/index' // Idem home component

import './App.css' // fichero css que nos sirve para darle estilo a nuestros components


class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' render={() => (
            <Home />
          )} />
          <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Ahora suponiendo que estamos desarrollando la app, nuestra url seria por ejemplo: **localhost:3000**.

Como le hemos dicho a nuestro `<Switch />` que cuando el prop `path` de el component `<Route />` coincida con la ruta `/`  nos renderize el component `<Home />`. Fijate que al prop `render` le pasamos una arrow function(es6). Y dentro de esta retornamos el component. Esto nos es muy util por que quizas antes de renderizar un el componente `<Home />` quieras introducir cierta logica,por ejemplo para renderizar uno u otro componente, si el usuario que hace la peticion esta logueado o no.

Ahora con lo que respecta a:

```
<Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
```

En este caso le estamos diciendo que cuando la url sea cualquier otra * (comodín) menos las que ya establecimos, entonces nos renderize directamente el component `<NotFound />`

**Último ejemplo:**

Si quisieramos que que nuestra app nos renderize el component `<Admin />` cuando la url sea localhost:3000/admin:

*Recordar que debemos importar el component para usarlo:*

```
import Admin from 'path_al_component'
```

*Luego*

```
  <Route path='/admin' component={Admin} />
```

> **React-router:** https://reacttraining.com/react-router/
>
> **Create-react-app:** https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

Comment: la primera variante me resuelve un poco pero la idea es tener como global menu que cuando abra algun path se me muestre un menu que lo tenga el componente, es como tener una variable global ejemplo: menu y cuando entre en /admin el component Admin cambie el valor del menu pero cuando entre en /admin/seguridad el componente AdminSecurity cambie el menu a [seguridad, roles, trazas]